# XElement wont return any media:content / xmlns:media breaks XElement

Tags: c#, rss, xml-namespaces, xelement

Here is my sample xml:

```
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'> 
<channel> 
    <title>Title of RSS feed</title> 
    <link>LINK</link> 
    <description>Details about the feed</description> 
    <language>en</language> 
    <item>
      <title>TITLE</title>
      <media:content url='http://LINK' type='' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss' />
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

My Code:

```
XElement rss = XElement.Parse(xml);
XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";

var item = rss.Element("channel").Elements("item").First();
var mediaa = item.Element(media + "content"); //this part doesn't work as expected
var url = mediaa.Attribute("url");
```

it seems as if the "`xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss'`" part of the `media:content` tag is breaking the `.Element(media + "content")`.
(I can not change the feed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong namespace. There's no "/" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
XNamespace media = XNamespace.Get("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
```

Also note that you have to fix it in the media:content element as well, it should say

```
  <media:content url='http://LINK' type='' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Should that be

XNamespace media = "{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}";

ie with curly braces?

Comment: No, that doesnt help, as I said the xmlns:media part breaks the Element(media + "content").
 (it works if the xml doesnt contain xmlns:media in the media:content tag)